# Select project category change event JIRA 6.3.15

Tags: jira, project, jira-plugin

I'm using JIRA 6.3.15. I'm using `ProjectCategoryChangeEvent` to catch the event of changing project category. When this event is triggered I have to do something like that: A custom field "X" have a context for old project category "A" and a context for new project category "B" and if the X context for A is different of X context for B do something. The problem is that the event is triggered after the project category change is done and because of that the contexts will merge and always will be the same.

Does someone know how can I trigger the event before the contexts are merged?

Answer (score 0):

I see that ProjectCategoryChangeEvent has getNewProjectCategory() and getOldProjectCategory() methods that return new and old category when the event is fired.
Why do you need a custom field for this?